# Determine if a Turing Machine M, on input w, will move its head to the left, at least once

Tags: formal-languages

Here is a problem from my formal languages class

> Consider the following problem: Determine if a Turing Machine M, on input w,             will move its head to the left, at least once.
>
> > 1. Is this problem decidable?
> > 2. Can Rice's theorem be applied on this case?

and here is my attempt to answer (1):

---

Define M' as a turing machine that takes a pair (M,w) as input, where M is a turing machine encoded in some form recognized by M' and w is the input to M.

M' stops and accepts (M,w) whenever the head of the simulated machine M moves to the left while processing input w

For a particular input to M' (M,w), construct the turing machine P as follows:

- P executes M' on (M,w)
- P stops and accepts any input if M' accepts (M,w)

We have reduced the Universal Turing Machine U to P. Since we know that L(U) is not decidable, we conclude that L(P) is not decidable. Consequently, M' is not decidable

---

As to the applicability of Rice's theorem, I'm not sure...

"Any nontrivial property about the language recognized by a Turing machine is undecidable"

moving the head of the machine is not a property of the language itself, it is a property of the machine...

thoughts, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea that Rice's theorem is inapplicable is correct. For the theorem to hold, we want to have whenever $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$, $M_1$ satisfies the property iff $M_2%$ does. This is evidently not true of the property presently under consideration. Think of two machines identifying a regular language (i.e. recognizable in a single pass), but one machine backs up all the way to the left, while the other does not.

But your reduction does not make sense. At a very high level, the point of a reduction is something like: "I know problem $P_1$ is hard. If I could solve problem $P_2$, voila! Here is a method to solve problem $P_1$. But this should not be possible. Therefore, $P_2$ has to be hard." Typically, $P_1$ is the halting problem, and you want $P_2$ to be the "left-mover" problem. So, given an instance of the halting problem, you manufacture an instance of the left-mover problem. If I read your reduction correctly, you're doing it in the opposite direction.

Now, something else is wrong with your solution. The problem is decidable! Here is the algorithm sketch: observe that if $M$ never moves left on $w$, it is making a single pass on the string. Eventually, $M$ finishes reading $w$ (which is of finite length), and starts reading spaces. Now, you simply look at which state $q$ $M$ is in when it finishes reading $w$, and look at the subgraph of states it visits on reading spaces. None of these should ever involve moving to the left.

Comment: Totally makes sense now. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually decidable. The fault in your solution is that $M'$ can accept $<M>, <w>$ without moving left and $M'$ may never halt simulation $<M>$ on $<w>$ but it might move left. You've missed these 2 cases in your solution.

Now coming to the algorithm to solve this problem. 
Case 1) If $M$ halts on $w$ and it never moved left, reject it.
Case 2) If $M$ ever moves left, halt and accept.
Case 3) If $M$ stays on the same location for more than $|Q|.|Γ|$ moves, then it means that a configuration gets repeated again which means $M$ stays on this location forever. So, reject it.
Case 4) Otherwise, in this case, $M$ doesn't get stuck at a location, so it actively moves right. So, after a finite number of steps($< |Q|.|Γ|.|w|$) $M$ crosses the input $w$. So, now it encounters a blank symbol. Suppose it is on a blank symbol with state $q$. In a finite number of steps, it moves right and changes the state to $q'$. If $q' = q$, then that means it is on an infinite loop(and moves right forever). One can easily check that after $|Q|^2.|Γ|$ computations, the state gets repeated for sure. If the tape head crosses w and even after $|Q|^2.|Γ|$ computations, tape head doesn't move left, then it'll never move left. So, reject it.
So, in a finite amount of computation one can determine whether a TM on an input ever moves left or not. So, this is decidable